# F# Async.SwitchToContext vs. Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, f#

Are these two functions ( `doSync` and `postToUI` ) doing the same kind of evaluation on the (WPF) UI thread?

Or is there a subtle difference?

My question is less about coding style but more about what is actually happening behind the scene.

```
open System.Threading
open System.Windows.Threading

let doSync (f:'a -> 'b) x = 
    async{  do! Async.SwitchToContext SynchronizationContext.Current
            return f x
         } |> Async.RunSynchronously


let postToUI : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b =
    fun f x ->
      Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new System.Func<_>(fun () -> f x), [||])      
      |> unbox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be the same, it depends.

`Async.SwitchToContext` will make the async continuations run on `SynchronizationContext.Post`. What it's posting to entirely depends on the context of the call to `doSync`.

WPF has a message pump system - the Dispatcher, which schedules units of work on the main (the UI) thread.

Now, `postToUI` will certainly run the delegate on a dispatcher frame.
If you call `doSync` from within a WPF context, `SynchronizationContext.Current` will be
`DispatcherSynchronizationContext`. And [under the hood](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherSynchronizationContext.cs,83):

```
    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
    {
       _dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, d, state);         
    }

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
    {
        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(_priority, d, state);
    }
```

you can see that `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` ends up calling `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

So, to summarise:

- If you are in a WPF context, `doSync` will call
  `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.
- If you are not in a WPF context, `doSync`
  will call whatever implements `Post` on the current
  `SynchronizationContext`.
- If you are in either context, `postToUI`
  will call `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

P.S.

Since `Invoke` blocks until return, and `SwitchToContext` actually uses `Post`, `doSync` is more `postToUI`, and `postToUI` is more `doSync`.

Comment: thanks Asti, so in WPF the `Post` call also blocks in the same way because of the `Async.RunSynchronously` ?

Comment: Yes, it's blocking. The other subtle difference is that `BeginInvoke` doesn't run immediately, but queues it for execution.